# Using the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem to prove Poincare inequality for a function vanishing at one point

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded Lipschitz domain. When $1\leq p < n$, apparently $p< p^* = np/(n-p)$, hence
$$
W^{1,p}(\Omega )\subset \subset L^{p}(\Omega ),
$$
and for any $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
$$
\|u\|_{L^p}\leq C \|u \|_{W^{1,p}}\;.
$$
To bound using the seminorm like the following Poincare inequality
$$
\|u\|_{L^p}\leq C |u |_{W^{1,p}} := C \left(\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p\right)^{1/p}\;,\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
we need some extra conditions like 
$$
u = 0 \;\text{ on }\partial \Omega,\tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\int_{\Omega}u = 0,\tag{2}
$$
or
$$
\int_{U} u =0, \text{ where } U\subset \Omega, \text{ and }\operatorname{meas}_{n}(U) \neq 0. \tag{3}
$$
The proof is pretty standard by using the sequential compactness to reach a contradiction.

---

Normally the conditions like (1), (2), or (3) avoid using pointwise value because $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ may not necessarily embedded in $C^{0,\alpha}$ spaces.

Here if we assume the extra continuous condition like $u$ being continuous, I could prove the following:

- **Proposition 1**: $u\in V:= W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C^0(\overline{\Omega})$, $u(z) = 0$ for some $z\in \overline{\Omega}$, then ($\dagger$) is true:
  $$
  \|u\|_{L^p}\leq C |u |_{W^{1,p}}\;.\tag{$\dagger$}
  $$

*Proof*: Assume otherwise, then there exists a sequence $\{v_n\}\subset V$ such that 
$$
\|v_n\|_{L^p} = 1, \;\text{ and }\; |v_n |_{W^{1,p}} < \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Now by Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem, there exists a subsequence $\{v_m\}\subset \{v_n\}$ such that
$$
v_m\to v \; \text{ in } \|\cdot\|_{L^p}.
$$
Moreover, the $L^p$ convergence further implies there exists a subsequence $\{v_j\}\subset \{v_m\}$ converging a.e., and by $V$ itself being $C^0$, we have
$$
v_j\to v \; \text{ in } \|\cdot\|_{L^p}, \; \text{ and }
v(z) = 0.
$$
By triangle inequality it is straightforward to verify that 
$$\|v\|_{L^p} = 1.\tag{4}$$

Now, by integrating against a smooth test function $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$, $|v_j|_{W^{1,p}}<1/j$, and bounded convergence theorem, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega} v\,\partial_{x_i} \phi = 
\int_{\Omega} \lim_{j\to \infty}v_j\,\partial_{x_i} \phi
\lim_{j\to \infty}\int_{\Omega} v_j\,\partial_{x_i} \phi
=-\lim_{j\to \infty}\int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_i} v_j\,\phi = 0.
$$
As a result, the limit $v$ is a constant, also $v$ now must be 0 due to $v(z) = 0$. This contradicts with (4). Q.E.D.

---

The result first does not look quite right, since no point values are allowed in general (as aforementioned conditions (1), (2), and (3) do).

So now my question is:

- Is Proposition 1 correct?
- If not, is there any counterexample in simple domains like a ball?

Comment: The proposition is true only in dimension 1. In higher dimensions, a constant function can be approximated in the Sobolev norm by continuous functions vanishing at finitely many points

Comment: Does $|u|_{W^{1,p}}$ here denote $\left(\int |\nabla u|^p\right)^{1/p}$?

Comment: To build a bit upon what @almaz said: In one dimension, we have the embedding $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \subset C(\Omega)$. Point evaluations (i.e., integration w.r.t. a Dirac measure) are continuous functionals on $C(\Omega)$, regardless of the dimension. With the aforementioned embedding, in one dimension, they are also (well-defined) continuous functionals on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, so that their respective kernel is closed, and we can factor with respect to those kernels. The functional $f \mapsto \int_U f$ in well-defined and continuous on $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ regardless of the dimension.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes.

Comment: @almaz Any references? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical counterexample is like the following.  For concreteness, let's take $p=1$ and $n=2$, and $\Omega = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $$f_n(t) = \begin{cases} nt, & 0 \le t \le 1/n \\ 1, & t > 1/n.\end{cases}$$ 
Set $v_n(x) = f_n(|x|)$, so $v_n$ is continuous and $v_n(0)=0$.  (If you like you may modify the function $f_n$ slightly to make it $C^\infty$.)

You can check that $|\nabla v_n(x)| = n$ for $0 < |x| < 1/n$ and $|\nabla v_n(x)| = 0$ for $1/n < x < 1$.  Thus $|v_n|_{W^{1,1}} = n \cdot m(B(0,1/n)) = \pi/n \to 0$.  But $v_n \to 1$ monotonically almost everywhere, so $v_n \to 1$ in $L^1(\Omega)$.

The flaw in your proof is in looking at the properties of $v$.  You defined $v$ as the $L^p$ and a.e. limit of the $v_n$, so it's only well-defined up to null sets.  In general you can't choose a continuous representative for it (you claimed you could but didn't justify it), so speaking of $v(0)$ doesn't really make sense.  In this example you can choose a continuous representative (namely 1) but you don't have $v_n \to v$ pointwise everywhere, so using that representative you cannot conclude $v(0)=0$.

Comment: Somehow on a second thought, Proposition 1 seems okay for $W^{k,p}$ that can be embedded in $C^{0,1}$. The biggest problem is in the proof but not the proposition itself.